# Multiple File upload and send in email - AppEngine & Blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

Hi I am new at this so please be gentle!

I have a HTML web form that I need to allow for multiple file upload using Python/Django/AppEngine. The files should be stored within the Blobstore when uploaded and then sent as attachments within an email which will be sent via the system.

Could someone provide a simple code example of how to do this multiple upload and sending in an email please, or even point me in the right direction please? The sending of an email is easy, but it is the uploading and attaching where I am not so sure.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

- [Uploading multiple files to the blobstore](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-part-3-Multiple-upload-support)
- [Sending mail with attachments](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/attachments.html)